# Visual Studio Update 15.8.1+ Build Problems

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I noticed after update Visual Studio to 15.8.1 and above that our build server now when it builds a .net core 2.0 project the number of DLLs in the build now has increased almost like 2x over the amount that was included in the build previously. 
 We have some really big projects so the build size increase is noticeable and somewhat of a problem.  I don't think any settings have changed on our end...but maybe some buried default changed with the update?  Anyone know how to put things back the way they were previous?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question description is too broad, we could to know what happened for this issue. You need to build one of the problematic project and tell us which dll files are added. An example description will help us understand the problem. As test, you can download the previous version Visual Studio to verify if it related to VS update:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017#top

Comment: please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or before and after binary build logs (which would involve sharing some of your machine configuration, project file contents and source file names)

Comment: But VS product issues are best to directly take to MS at http://developercommunity.visualstudio.com either via the website or VS-integrated "report a problem" feature

Comment: This is what pisses me off about Microsoft products.  Everything was fine pre-update.  Post update, I get to spend a few hours debugging what we didn't break.  Annoying.